# Linq cannot translate my groupby/ordering query

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-6.0

I have a set of cars and I want to group them and then order them but I'm always receiving a linq translation error. The 'CarLink' property is a Guid, which links similar cars together (similar cars have the same CarLink Guid). I use GroupBy because DistinctBy can not be translated by linq. My result should be a list where only one of the similar cars is in the list and the list should be ordered by the creation date of the cars.

For pagination reasons, I need to do this query in one single call. Splitting the query ordering afterwards is therefore no option.

(I'm using EF-Core 6)

```
            var carsQuery = this._dataContext.Cars
                .AsNoTracking()
                .GroupBy(x => x.CarLink)
                .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).First())
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate);
            
            // filtering and pagination will be done here...

            // Endresult:
            var carsList = carsQuery.ToList();
```

Thank you for your help!

I tried todo the ordering first, before grouping and many other linq variations but ordering did not work then.

Comment: Which EF version? Specify in question tags.

Comment: `.AsNoTracking()` <-- Do you have a **good reason** for using this?

Comment: EF-Core 6 and i'm using .AsNoTracking() because I don't do any updates and for performance reasons.

Comment: Strange EF Core 6 should translate this query. Try without ordering, paginations, etc. after `Select()`

Comment: Order first then filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like `ROW_NUMBER` from previous answer, but if you need pure LINQ,
try the following workaround. It mimics what EF Core do with such grouping internally:

```cs
var cars = this._dataContext.Cars.AsNoTracking();
var carsQuery = 
    from d in cars.Select(c => new {c.CarLink}).Distinct()
    from c in cars.Where(c => c.CarLink == d.CarLink)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate)
        .Take(1)
    select c;

carsQuery = carsQuery
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate);
    // filtering and pagination will be done here...
```

Comment: This helped a lot! Much easier with the LINQ query syntax. Thank you for your help! only one thing: carsQuery cannot be declared two times ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that EF Core can't correctly translate the ordering (and then filtering and pagination) coming aster the group by, you can trick it with custom projection (but it seems that you will need to fetch some extra data):

```cs
var result = _dataContext.Cars
    .AsNoTracking()
    .GroupBy(x => x.CarLink)
    .Select(gr => new
    {
        CreatedDate = gr.Max(x => x.CreatedDate),
        Car = gr.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).First(),
    })
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDate)
    .Take(2)
    .ToList();
```

For extra filtering you will need to have similar approach (i.e. add the data to custom projection with something like `SomePropToFilter = gr.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Select(c => c.SomePropToFilter).First()`, though check generated query and analyze that performance is suitable).

Another option would be either filtering before grouping, or using `FromSql...` or writing some manual join via EF Core.