# EF Linq GroupBy expression could not be translated

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a `Case` object and a `Property` object such that a Property can have multiple Cases: the Case object has a `PropertyId` property.

I want to retrieve only the latest cases for each property so I am trying to use `GroupBy` in a way that avoids the n+1 query problem:

```
private IQueryable<Case> AllActiveCases()
        => _context.Cases.Where(c => c.DeletedAt == null);

...
var result = await AllActiveCases()
                       .GroupBy(c => c.PropertyId)
                       .SelectMany(cases => cases.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedAt).Take(1))
                       .AsNoTracking()
                       .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

However, this gives me

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Case>()
    .Where(c => c.DeletedAt == null)
    .GroupBy(c => c.PropertyId)
    .SelectMany(cases => cases
        .AsQueryable()
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedAt)
        .Take(1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

I am using EF Core 7.0.1.

I have checked for unsupported Linq methods (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but don't seem to be using any incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Select` with `First`:

```cs
var result = await AllActiveCases()
    .GroupBy(c => c.PropertyId)
    .Select(cases => cases.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedAt).First())
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Another approach (if you need multiple entries from group) would be to flatten client side:

```cs
var resultTmp = await AllActiveCases()
    .GroupBy(c => c.PropertyId)
    .Select(cases => cases.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedAt).Take(5))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
var result = resultTmp.SelectMany(t => t).ToList();
```

Comment: This answers my question, but leads to a similar error when used as one part of a join statement. I'll tackle that separately.

Comment: @u05sdb, check [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76737101/10646316)